# yaml syntactical error with_items loop with a list

Tags: ansible, yaml

trying to loop with a list to create a append a yaml file; getting some syntactical error ?
any idea how we can fix this ?

```
- name: "append yml"
  shell: echo "instances:\n\n   - name: all\n   - command: all\n   - arguments:\n     - cluster_name: dbtype{{ item }} all\n     - host: {{ipv4}}\n" >> /path/dbtype-config.yml
  shell: echo "     - auth_source: admin\n     - ssl: false\n     - ssl_insecure_skip_verify: false\n    - labels:\n     - env: env\n" >> /tmp/newrelic-infra/integrations.d/dbtype-config.yml
  with_items: "{{ instances.stdout_lines }}"
```

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.

The error appears to have been in '/ansible/projects/newrelic/dbtype_nr.yml': line 27, column 47, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
    - name: "update yml"
      shell: echo "instances:\n\n   - name: all\n   - command: all\n   - arguments:\n     - cluster_name: dbtype{{ item }} all\n     - host: {{ipv4}}\n" >> /path/dbtype-config.yml
                                          ^ here
```

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
```

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: replace : with {{':'}} will work and found this -https://serverfault.com/questions/807025/quoting-colon-in-ansible

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes or surround your entire expression with single quotes in your `shell` definition (non exhaustive list of possibilities, check a yaml tutorial like https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/ to understand all possibilities to define scalar values). Next, you cannot define the same yaml parameter in an object. You might not get an error but only your second `shell` definition will be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it's something similar to @Unknown's suggestion, put single quotes around the : inside of the echo.

Also, are you certain two shell commands will work inside of the single task? I would make two tasks, like:

```
- name: "append 1st yml"
  shell: echo 'first part'
  with_items: "{{ my_list }}"

- name: "append 2nd yml"
  shell: echo 'second part'
  with_items: "{{ my_list }}"
```

Comment: exactly this is 2nd question I wanted to create. Is there a way we can loop through list on ansible 2.0.0.1 on ubuntu xenial ?